# Binding ListBoxItem index to DataContext bound item using listboxitem index

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, listboxitem

Looking for the subject I found that it's possible to bind 
against listboxitem index only through value converter.

But I don't inderstand how to set the index to the datacontext property 
using index of current listboxitem.

For example, when index of the listboxitem changes I want to change the property of bound datacontext item.

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is an integer and bindable, if the property in the DataContext is also of type integer, you can just bind them normally without any converter.

Comment: That's the problem, that I need index, not the SelectedIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved with **ObservableCollection CollectionChanged** event.
On reordering of the listbox, *adding, sorting, removing* 
I get this event where I can modify index of the bound viewmodel item.